# Equality $(\frac{q}{p})^{\frac{p}{p+q}}+(\frac{q}{p})^{\frac{-q}{p+q}}=(\frac{q}{p})^{\frac{-q}{p+q}}\frac{p+q}{p}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I have this equality $$(\frac{q}{p})^{\frac{p}{p+q}}+(\frac{q}{p})^{\frac{-q}{p+q}}=(\frac{q}{p})^{\frac{-q}{p+q}}\frac{p+q}{p}$$
in which $p,q >0$.
I've tried to transform in some way but I have done is this:

$(\frac{q}{p})^{\frac{p}{p+q}}+(\frac{q}{p})^{\frac{-q}{p+q}}=(\frac{q}{p})^{\frac{-q}{p+q}}((\frac{q}{p})^{\frac{p-q}{p+q}}+1)$

but I can't understand why $((\frac{q}{p})^{\frac{p-q}{p+q}}+1)=\frac{p+q}{p}$

Is there same rule that I don't know?

Comment: The exponent numerator should be $p+q$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have $$\begin{align*}\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{\frac{p}{p+q}}+\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{\frac{-q}{p+q}}&=\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{\frac{-q}{p+q}}\left[\frac{\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{\frac p{p+q}}}{\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{\frac{-q}{p+q}}}+1\right]\\&=\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{\frac{-q}{p+q}}\left[\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{\frac{p\color{red}+q}{p+q}}+1\right]\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{\frac{p}{p+q}} + \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{\frac{-q}{p+q}} = \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{\frac{p+q-q}{p+q}} + \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{\frac{-q}{p+q}} = \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{\frac{-q}{p+q}+1} + \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{\frac{-q}{p+q}} = \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{\frac{-q}{p+q}} + \frac{q}{p}\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{\frac{-q}{p+q}} = \left(\frac{p}{q}\right)^{\frac{-q}{p+q}}\left(\frac{p+q}{p}\right) $$